# how can I contact Google about a domain misuse?

Tags: google, google-workspace

I was trying to add a newer domain of mine to my existing Google Apps account with an already set primary domain. Google Apps then returns the message that the domain is already in use by another account.

I tried finding a way to contact Google, but they have a wall up preventing anyone with an original Apps account from calling them.

There's a help page saying to try retrieving the password, but how is that even possible? I don't know the email address of the owner of the Apps account using my domain, and I don't know his/her name on the account, so I can't complete the form for retrieving any of the information.

Google Productforums is always a dead end.

Does anyone here know how to force a removal of a domain on Google Apps from someone that doesn't own it?

Comment: Is it a new domain or a reused one? If it's a new one it's almost impossible to tie a domain you don't own to an account, due to the strict security check. When adding a domain to Google Apps you have to verify that you are the owner of the domain by adding a txt record into the DNS settings of the domain.

Comment: The domain was registered before, but dropped, and then I registered it. Problem is the previous registrant also used Google Apps, but never removed it when it expired. I don't know how I can prove to Google that guy is no longer the registrant.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: If you domain is not a new one you might be out of luck. You will have to upgrade (or try the trial) to Apps for Business to escalate your problem to a google engineer.

Comment: It doesn't. It requires that I know the previous registrant's name and email address to retrieve their Google Apps account, and that's not the issue. The previous registrant also used Google Apps, but no longer owns the domain, and I have no way of removing the domain from their account.